# How to get list of files in a directory using date modified in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How do I get all the files based on date modified?
Here is my code:

```py
import glob
import os
import time

error_file_path = "C:\\python"
modificationTime = time.strftime(
    "%d/%m/%Y", time.localtime(os.path.getmtime(error_file_path))
)
df = []
while modificationTime:
    for error_filename in glob.glob(error_file_path + "aaaa*error_*.csv.bz2"):
        df.append(error_filename)
print(df)
```

`modificationTime` is the latest date modified in my directory. I have to loop all the files for this date with the format `aaaa*error_*.csv.bz2`.

Comment: Are you trying to sort file on the basis of date modified?

Comment: I dont have to sort but I want all files for the date modified.. we can sort all files by latest date as well .. and for that date pick all files

Comment: I don't think I understand you. what do you have in `error_file_path`,`date`, in your searching folder, expected output, from where `req_cols()` function came ......... ????? why are you doing this `error='data1'` there is nothing in your code where it is used!

Comment: I have edited my code. I want to loop through all the files for the latest date modified in my directory.